# "Please review / critique" in question's title

Tags: discussion, titles

Would it be wise to consider such posts as a subject for "auto" edit or add to the faq?

- It seems redundant to ask for review explicitly on the site which purpose is to review the code by community. It's like starting "Please answer" in title on another StackExchange site.
- It's annoying because it doesn't add anything to the title and "hides" the real title.
  Consider current situation:

  - Please critique Sorting algorithms implemented in C++
  - Please critique my C++ file parsing code
  - Please critique my Linked List implementation in C++

  vs (what could it be)

  - Sorting algorithms implemented in C++
  - C++ file parsing code
  - Linked List implementation in C++

Comment: *"Please review & suggest a way to improve this title"*

Answer (score 19):

I agree -- all questions that are present here are default *please critique*.

If there is some subtlety to what is being asked for, it should be explained in the question.

Feel free to edit these out of titles when you see them using suggested edits!