# Improved title filter

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, titles

I've just found the *[Improve “The Title Filter” responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117530/improve-the-title-filter-responses)* question on SO meta. It would be great to filter additionally words like "review", "please", "please review", "review request", "my code", "please critique", "critique" etc. on this site.

A related question: [“Please review / critique” in question's title](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354/please-review-critique-in-questions-title)

Comment: And I've just gotten confirmation that title filters can be [different per site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118923/does-the-title-filter-work-differently-per-site), so we can ask for specific filters...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, this probably should've been done long before now - it's clear this has become a persistent problem here.

Starting *now*, the following words/phrases are not allowed in titles:

- "review"
- "critique"
- "improve"
- "help with"
- "question" (unless followed by "mark")
- any sentence starting or ending with "help" or "problem"

I can't do much about the mess that's accumulated in the time since this was proposed, but hopefully this will discourage folks from making it *worse*.

Comment: It looks like "improved" should be added as well.  There are also a lot of questions in the form of "How can X be improved?"

Comment: 22 is a lot @Jamal?

Comment: Hm.  I thought I remember seeing more than that over time.  What were your search terms?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aimproved

Comment: I see.  Some questions might've been edited to remove that, but I don't know how many.  Either way, if it doesn't seem needed, then that's fine.