# Could we detect phrases like "not working" and "bug" in question titles and warn users?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, scope

It has been [mentioned recently](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/how-should-we-revisit-our-standard-close-reasons) that ~62% of close votes come from the "broken code" or "code not yet written" category. I'm wondering if we could help lower that percentage by detecting certain key phrases in the title (or possibly body) of the question and give a red warning banner before the user posts it?

For example, this week, I've seen:

- [Project Euler 122 Program Not Working?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185283/project-euler-122-program-not-working)
- [Bug in my fractal code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185267/bug-in-my-fractal-code)
- [Creating a string with in a method?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185239/creating-string-with-in-method)

I notice some patterns in these questions. Words like "bug", phrases like "not working" and question titles ending in a question mark seem to have a high occurrence (in my very very brief look) of getting put on hold. Would it be worth detecting some of these things and warning users that their post may be off-topic? Would anyone be able to do an analysis of "on hold" questions and see if there are correlations with certain phrases?

Comment: Related: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/435/improved-title-filter

Comment: Related: [Code Review Clippy](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7298)

Comment: We do have *some* clippy-like features, like if you write the title "Help me with this code" you get a few popups, we should definitely get such for "Bug" and "Not working" too.

Comment: That would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is done. [My bug is not working](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=My%20bug%20is%20not%20working)

[image: A title of "My bug is not working" will now produce a warning. Other titles containing one or both of these phrases should do the same.]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Hopefully this will reduce our number of posts to close.

Comment: Would it be possible to add questions starting with "why"? Such as [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185827/why-is-my-implementation-of-inits-failing).